# How do I invert the direction of my circles with mouse proximity on javascript canvas?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I would like to swap the direction of the circles moving when the mouse gets near but I am struggling to figure out how.

Be gentle, I'm new to this.

- The `conte` is just context and my version of saying `c.something`.

**Code**:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

var conte = canvas.getContext('2d');

var l = 200;
var dl = 7;
var radius = 30;

var mouse = {
    x: undefined,
    y: undefined
}

window.addEventListener('mousemove', 

    function(event) {
        mouse.x = event.x;
        mouse.y = event.y;
        console.log(mouse);
    })

    function animate() {
       requestAnimationFrame(animate);

       conte.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)';
       conte.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

       conte.beginPath();

       conte.arc(l, 200, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
       conte.strokeStyle = '#E3DACD';
       conte.stroke();
       conte.fillStyle = '#B8B0A6';
       conte.fill();

       if (l + radius > innerWidth || l - radius < 0) {
           dl = -dl;
       }

       l += dl;

       conte.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)';
       conte.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

       conte.beginPath();

       conte.arc(l, 300, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
       conte.strokeStyle = '#B0B1A1';
       conte.stroke();
       conte.fillStyle = '#98998B';
       conte.fill();

       conte.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)';
       conte.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

       conte.beginPath();

       conte.arc(l, 400, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
       conte.strokeStyle = '#6C7974';
       conte.stroke();
       conte.fillStyle = '#545E5A';
       conte.fill();

       conte.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)';
       conte.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

       conte.beginPath();

       conte.arc(l, 500, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
       conte.strokeStyle = '#935F39';
       conte.stroke();
       conte.fillStyle = '#7D5130';
       conte.fill();

       conte.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.05)';
       conte.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

       conte.beginPath();

       conte.arc(l, 100, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
       conte.strokeStyle = '#E7B99F';
       conte.stroke();
       conte.fillStyle = '#CFA58E';
       conte.fill();

   };

if (mouse.x > radius +10 || mouse.x < radius) {


    if (l + radius > innerWidth || l - radius < 0) {
        dl = -dl;
    }

    l -= dl;

};


animate();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas">
</canvas>
```

I have a feeling it's the end bit.

Comment: I played around with this about 2 years ago ( https://codepen.io/doughensel/pen/qNRdmG?editors=0010 ) so my memory is a bit fuzzy ... but it's fun with math :) you want to find the cursor's position relative to any dot (so a lot of looping through available dots), find how close the cursor is and which angle it is coming from, and set a max threshold to return the dot to its home spot once the mouse leaves the general area.

Comment: Cheers, your design is awesome!

Comment: what you mean by "the mouse gets near" do you want any ball to revert it's direction when you hover on it or when you click on any ball

Comment: Yeah, So when the mouse is moved close to the ball the ball then moves the opposite way.

Comment: (i apologize, before Tscallacka's edit, I didn't see the code in action -- my codepen demo may not be valid for this :P I just read it as my old problem but not as your current problem)

Comment: No problem. Thanks anyway!

Comment: What is that "l -= dl" about?

Comment: I was trying to reverse what I did to get them moving in one direction but evidently failed aha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont compare the mouse position inside the animate function, so it wont be done every frame. Also you dont compare the mouse position with the circles position at all. So assuming "l" is the horizontal position of the circle and vertical position is 200, radius is 30:

```
if(mouse.y < 230 && mouse.y > 170 && mouse.x < l + 30 && mouse.x > l - 30) {
    //the mouse touches the circle
    dl = -dl;
}
```

Comment: Ah I see, sorry this must be so frustrating for you pros :'), you were right about the 'l'. This is appreciated!

Comment: I think its kind of refreshing to get back to mathematical position calculation, havent done this in a while :)

Comment: To be honest I envy you ahaha

Comment: It Works!!!! Is it possible for it to register on all circles or just the top one?

Comment: @PaulRoscoe If you create a "l" for every circle and compare every "l" with the mouse it should work. Dont forget to use the right vertical position, though.